# CSS float consider container's width stretch

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, css-float

I have a `div` with some `span` tags inside that are containers for `input` `button`s.
Now I want my last button to always `float` to the right. Sometimes the container `div`s `width` is overflown (the container's width is more like a min-width). 
In FF it works almost nice with `float:right`, but in IE8 it renders it to the right of the whole page, not to the right of my container.

How can I float this last button (which is a "Back" button to the right of my `div` container) so:
1. It will always stay on the right (no matter if the div's width is `overflow`n or not)
2. It would work in both FF and IE8.
3. Notice that in FF the 5th button gets rendered closer to the 4th that the 4th to the 3rd. Is there another way to do this which does not have this problem or should I just use a `left` property to fix it?

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cge8/7/) . (check it out in IE8)

Summary: I want the `float:right` to consider whether the container `div`s width is stretched or not. (If stretched point after the last `span` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. I am not using `float: right` but `position:absolute` and `right:0` which has the same effect it the parent container's position is set to `relative`.

Answer (score 0):

use the ul tag and create a list then use css to define the way it floats like this

```
<html>
<div class="hello_list">
<ul>

<li><a"put a link attribute here or an anchor">hello 1</a></li>
<li><a"put a link attribute here or an anchor">hello 1</a></li>
<li><a"put a link attribute here or an anchor">hello 1</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</html>
```

then in your css style sheet do this

```
html{  }
body{  }

ul{  }
ul li{ float:left;}
ul li a{ color:"put a color here"; }
ul li a:visited{ color:"put a color here";}
ul li a:hover{ color:"put a color here"; }
ul li a:active{color:"put a color here"; }
```

and check your hierarchy as well it will help in the long run to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I do not see how is the last button always floated to the right?

Comment: make sure as well as ur heirarchy that you define the amount of space that the class takes up like this in your CSS style sheet: 1 sec ill post is in a regular awnser

Answer (score 0):

make sure as well as ur heirarchy that you define the amount of space that the class takes up like this in your CSS style sheet:

```
.hello_list<------use an underscore for all spaces in class names some browsers dont like spaces also do this with your file names for all links.
{
width:"define you width in pixels here"
height:"define your height here"
padding-right:;
padding-left:;
padding-top:;
padding-bottom:;
margin-left:;
margin-right:;
```

define all your sides with those tags beware that margin tag will move all your divs over not just your .hello_list
    }

i hope i helped GL!=)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. I don't get how is that last <span> going to float to the right. Moreover I do not use <ul> and <li> but <div> and <span>.